# How should Counter-Strike global offensive be tagged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Now that the game is playable via beta invites on Steam, questions about it may start popping up.

Obviously, [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive) is too long, so should it be:

1. [cs-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs-global-offensive)
2. [global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-offensive)
3. [counter-strike-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go)
4. [cs-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs-go)
5. Something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For clarity's sake, I would do the opposite of what Oak suggests: create [cs-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs-global-offensive) as the master with [counter-strike-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go) as a synonym. "CS" seems to be a well-known abbreviation, and even [Googling `cs`](https://www.google.ca/search?q=cs) results in "Counter Strike" as the first result for me. The synonym will still result in the autocomplete working properly.

Comment: If this is the agreed upon answer can I also suggest modifying the master tag for counter-strike-source to cs-source, for consistency. The original tag can stay as is, it will probably get a lot of usage for people intending to ask about CS:GO.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for [counter-strike-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go), with [cs-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs-global-offensive) marked as its synonym. Having the tag start with the game name is useful because of our auto-complete.

Comment: I would have it the other way for clarity.  "CS" seems to be a well-known abbreviation, and even Googling `cs` results in "Counter Strike" as the first result for me.  The synonym will still result in the autocomplete working properly.

Comment: @MatthewRead You make a good argument and I will upvote you if you post it as an answer :)

Comment: Cool, I've done so :)