# Rename [counter-strike-go] into [counter-strike-global-offensive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Since the tag length limit was increased to 35 characters, I suggest renaming [counter-strike-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go) into [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive) (31 characters), as it is no longer [too long](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/how-should-counter-strike-global-offensive-be-tagged), keeping the old tag as a synonym.

Comment: Csgo makes me think its a mobile game like pokemon go lol

Comment: @Fredy31 To unlock AK-47, you need to walk 10 more kilometers today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Done.**

- [counter-strike-cz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-cz) → [counter-strike-condition-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-condition-zero)
- [counter-strike-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go) → [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive)
- [csgo-overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csgo-overwatch), [counter-strike-overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-overwatch) → [counter-strike-go-overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go-overwatch)

Answer (score 1):

While we're fixing the tag for *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, we should also cleanup the other Counter Strike tags.

- [counter-strike-cz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-cz) → [counter-strike-condition-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-condition-zero) (29)
- [counter-strike-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go) → [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive) (31)
- [csgo-overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csgo-overwatch) → [counter-strike-go-overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go-overwatch) (27)

The *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Overwatch* tag would still need to be abbreviated, as [counter-strike-global-offensive-overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive-overwatch) (41) would be a bit too long.

<sub>**Side note**: I'm surprised the overwatch tag wasn't synonimized with [counter-strike-overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-overwatch) (24)</sub>